Electron app process is named after app description
When making an Electron based desktop app for Windows, I noticed that upon building it with electron-builder and launching the executable (portable), the process name in Task Manager is the app's description field set in package.json:

This project's full code is on GitHub. How could I make this look something like Botcord as supposed? Any help is appreciated.

This seems to be a bug in electron-builder versions 25.x, you can downgrade to 24.13.3 or switch to the alpha release 26.0.0-alpha.3. Check out this issue for more details
